# dereferencing SDL_Surfaces?

Tags: c++, pointers, copy, sdl

is there any way to copy a SDL surface to another, like creating a backup copy, without modifying the original when the copy is modified? `*surface = *original_surface` dosnt work. SDL_Surface does not have any constructors, so i cant do anything like `surface = new SDL_Surface (original_surface)`. currently, i am opening the original image constantly, but it takes longer to open the image than for one loop to finish. this causes a lot of lagging, and eventually errors, causing my program to end

Comment: You can create a compatible surface once (same format, same size), and just blit the original into the copy.

Comment: *facepalm. put that in an answer, and ill check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new compatible surface:

```
copy = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(flags, width, height, original->format.BitsPerPixel,
                            original->format.Rmask, original->format.Gmask,
                            original->format.Bmask, original->format.Amask);
```

And then blit the original into the copy:

```
SDL_BlitSurface(original, NULL, copy, NULL);
```